# What to do with unwanted amplitudes?

Tags: r, signal-processing, fft

I am working in a signal processing application. The idea is to filter out noise, and I found that most of the data I'm working with has a normal distribution. (CLT)

I ran an FFT and as expected the data still looks like a normal distribution in amplitudes. But every dataset that I have looked at has an unusual amplitude bump at about 4 standard deviations from the mean.

My question is, what is usually done with these amplitudes?

This is an example of the distribution of frequency amplitudes:

[image: Example of qplot of a signal in frequency domain]

My first thought was to simply remove the far-out amplitudes or remap them closer to the mean (I used    rnorm    ), but I'm sure other people have faced the same situation.

Here is a test that produces very interesting results. Slightly different distribution means will often produce outlier amplitudes:

```
    a <- rnorm(10000)
    b <- rnorm(500,1,1)
    u <- sample(union(a,b))
    qplot(Re(fft(u)))
```

[image]

Comment: Since this question is more about the theory/concept rather than implementation, I think it might be better suited for other stackexchange sites: cross validated or mathematics stack exchange.

Comment: In any case, some code and data would be nice. What sort of signal is this? Is there a theoretical explanation for that outlier frequency band? What would be the theoretical implications of removing it?

Comment: First, this pattern repeats on several sorts of signals; as long as they are a normal distribution with noise.                                               About theoretical explanations and implications: My best bet at an explanation is that these outliers come from different distributions. Removing these frequencies would probably shift every data point closer to the real distribution, but I haven't done the math and would really like to know what others are doing first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still a little difficult to see what you're really asking about. If you're asking about how to deal with outliers you're better off browsing Q&As over on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=handling%20outliers). It's too broad for this site.

However, if you're asking about why you get that little bump in your plot, and how it can be removed, I think I can help.

To call it an outlier wouldn't be quite right, it's more of an artefact of the fourier transform. It occurs because your signal has a slight [DC offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_bias), and the way to avoid this artefact is to remove this DC offset. The simplest way to remove it is to just shift the whole signal uniformly so that the mean amplitude is at 0. This is usually sufficient, but sometimes you'll have to de-trend the signal or apply a high-pass filter.

```
set.seed(1)
sig1 <- sample(c(rnorm(1e4), rnorm(500, 1, 1)))
ft1 <- fft(sig1)

sig2 <- sig1 - mean(sig1)
ft2 <- fft(sig2)

yl <- c(-280, 430)
par(mfrow=c(2, 1), mar=c(2, 3, 0.1, 0.1))
plot(Re(ft1)[1:(length(ft1)/2)], type="l", ylim=yl, xlab="", ylab="Original")
plot(Re(ft2)[1:(length(ft2)/2)], type="l", ylim=yl, xlab="", ylab="Centred")
```

[image]